# Tomcat clustering mechanism and session replication is not working on tomcat 8.5.78

Tags: java, tomcat, session-replication

I am working on a project where I need to replicate sessions on two different tomcats. I configured Nginx as a load balancer. Configured two tomcats to make two different nodes.

**My requirement**: Suppose two nodes are running and the session of node one is replicated in node two. And end-user is getting response from node one. If node one is down then the user will not get session out and continue with node two with the same session.

**Whats happening now**: Two nodes are running and session is replicated to both nodes. User getting response from node one. Node one down and user gets a session-out message.

I configured the tomcat clustering mechanism like tomcat documentation from this [site](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cluster-howto.html)
I configured tomcat 1's `server.xml` file like

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
                 channelSendOptions="6">

          <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.BackupManager"
                   expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                   notifyListenersOnReplication="true"
                   mapSendOptions="6"/>
          <!--
          <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
                   expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                   notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
          -->
          <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
            <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                        address="228.0.0.4"
                        port="45564"
                        frequency="500"
                        dropTime="3000"/>
            <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                      address="auto"
                      port="5000"
                      selectorTimeout="100"
                      maxThreads="6"/>

            <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
              <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
            </Sender>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatchInterceptor"/>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.ThroughputInterceptor"/>
          </Channel>

          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
                 filter=".*\.gif|.*\.js|.*\.jpeg|.*\.jpg|.*\.png|.*\.htm|.*\.html|.*\.css|.*\.txt"/>

          <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                    tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                    deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
                    watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                    watchEnabled="false"/>

          <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
        </Cluster>
```

And tomcat 2's `server.xml` file like

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
                 channelSendOptions="6">

          <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.BackupManager"
                   expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                   notifyListenersOnReplication="true"
                   mapSendOptions="6"/>
          <!--
          <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
                   expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                   notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
          -->
          <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
            <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                        address="228.0.0.4"
                        port="45564"
                        frequency="500"
                        dropTime="3000"/>
            <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                      address="auto"
                      port="5001"
                      selectorTimeout="100"
                      maxThreads="6"/>

            <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
              <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
            </Sender>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatchInterceptor"/>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.ThroughputInterceptor"/>
          </Channel>

          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
                 filter=".*\.gif|.*\.js|.*\.jpeg|.*\.jpg|.*\.png|.*\.htm|.*\.html|.*\.css|.*\.txt"/>

          <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                    tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                    deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
                    watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                    watchEnabled="false"/>

          <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
        </Cluster>
```

My `web.xml` file of my spring project is

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

  <display-name>Enterprise Web App</display-name>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name >springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!--start real ip filter for ngnix-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>RealIPFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.brainstation.corporate.ib.webapp.provider.ip.RealIPFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RealIPFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!--end real ip filter for ngnix-->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>web-app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>web-app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <name>EB_JSESSIONID</name>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>

    <distributable/>

</web-app>
```

And my nginx configuration on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file

```
    upstream backend {
            ip_hash;
            server localhost:7070 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
            server localhost:7080 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
            #server localhost:7090 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    
    
        #server_name hellobs23.com
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    
    
    
                root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


        location / {
                proxy_pass http://backend;
                error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
      }


        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

And one interesting thing is the same configuration working on another project but not working on my project. I have been desperately looking for a solution for 4 days. Could not find anything that could give me relief.

Comment: ANd what isn't working? You get errors, no replication or what?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have edited my question. Can you please check it.

Comment: Did you configure nginx properly, which is that it goes randomly to server 1 or 2 and not has session affinity or something alike configured.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added Nginx configuration. And with this same configuration, another project is working fine. But mine one is not working.

Comment: I'm not that good at Nginx so I cannot comment on that. But the fact that a config works for X doesn't mean it works for Y. If there are version differences, network differences etc. things can (and will) act differently.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible solutions:

1. Set jvmRoute in Engine tag
2. Change backup manager to delta manager
3. Change Multicast to Static membership

I am not familiar with Nginx, but seems that Nginx is not redirecting requests according to jessionid.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. I do understand that you cannot make comments yet due your reputation score, but please refrain from asking question in an answer if you're not providing a possible solution (You can rephrase your questions as examples, so it is better suited as an answer). I recommend you bookmark this and try to get enough reputation to ask for clarification properly, as a comment.

Comment: @JettoMartínez I have edit my answer to provide possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can also use memcache session manager to solve your issue. Please refer the link for description
[memcache session manager](https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager/wiki)

And set up information can be found on this link
[Setup and configuration](https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager/wiki/SetupAndConfiguration#overview-over-available-system-properties-all-optional)